# Q-Learning Table converges to -inf

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I tried to solve the [aigym mountain-car problem](https://github.com/openai/gym/wiki/MountainCar-v0) with my own q-learning implementation.

After trying around different things it started to work really good, but after a while (20k Episodes * 1000 Samples per Episode) I noticed that my the values stored in my Q-table got to big and so it stored the value -inf.

During the simulation I used to following code:

```
for t in range(SAMPLE_PER_EPISODE):

    observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    R[state, action] = reward

    history.append((state,action,reward))

    max_indexes = np.argwhere(Q[state,] == np.amax(Q[state,])).flatten()
    action = np.random.choice(max_indexes)
```

For learning I used the following code after each episode:

```
#train
latest_best = 0
total_reward = 0
for entry in reversed(history):
    Q[entry[0],entry[1]] = Q[entry[0],entry[1]] + lr * (entry[2] + latest_best * gamma)

    latest_best = np.max(Q[entry[0],:])
    total_reward += entry[2]
```

I got really good results with that algorithm but the problem was - as explained above - that the Q-Values went really fast to -inf

I think I implemented the Q-Algorithm wrong, but after changing it to the following implementation, it doesn't work anymore (nearly as good as it did before):

```
#train
latest_best = 0
total_reward = 0
for entry in reversed(history):
    # Here I changed the code
    Q[entry[0],entry[1]] = Q[entry[0],entry[1]] + lr * (entry[2] + latest_best * gamma - Q[entry[0],entry[1]])

    latest_best = np.max(Q[entry[0],:])
    total_reward += entry[2]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What values did you choose for `lr` and `gamma`? I'm suspecting that they are too big and `Q[entry[0],entry[1]] =` will just keep growing. Also, you might want to refactor your code so that you have variable names like `action` and `state` instead of `entry[...]`, it's hard to understand what the code actually does.

Comment: lr = 0.99, gamma = 0.8. Shouldn't it not grow as long as these values are < 1? I will refactor the code in the example tomorrow with my laptop :)

Answer (score 6):

I think there are two problems with your code:

1. Firstly, your learning rate is probably too high (lr = 0.99 from your comment) and your discounting factor (`gamma` = 0.8) might be, too.

The book [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book.html) by Richard S. Sutton, one of the founding fathers of Reinforcement learning, is available online and I highly recommend you use it as a reference.

Q-Learning is a special case of [Temporal Difference Learning](http://incompleteideas.net/book/ebook/node60.html) and [subchapter 6.2](http://incompleteideas.net/book/ebook/node62.html) mostly uses learning rates smaller than 0.15.

2. Assuming that `entry[0]` is x_k, `entry[1]` is u_k and `entry[2]` is r_{k+1}, then this line

   ```
    Q[entry[0],entry[1]] = Q[entry[0],entry[1]] + lr * (entry[2] + latest_best * gamma - Q[entry[0],entry[1]])
   ```

is equivalent to

```
    Q[x_k, u_k] = Q[x_k, u_k] + lr * (r_{k+1} + latest_best * gamma - Q[x_k, u_k])
```

If this is supposed to represent the formula
[image]
there is a problem with your first version, because you basically keep summing up rewards that are only slightly discounted. The second version with the additional `-Q[x_k, u_k]` should be correct.

**Other SO questions you might want to look at:**

- [Learning rate of a Q learning agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011825/learning-rate-of-a-q-learning-agent).
- [Q-Learning values get too high](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37524472/q-learning-values-get-too-high)